# Differential equation problem with multiple derivatives: $y'' - 2y' + y = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone help me with this differential equation, or give me some some advice on how to solve it?

$$y'' - 2y' + y = 0$$

Comment: make the ansatz $$y=e^{\lambda x}$$

Comment: What do you know of linear differential equations?

Comment: Here's a rather [dense overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a second-order linear homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients since it is in the form:
$$ay''+by'+cy=0~\text{ where }~a\neq 0$$

---

To solve these, we can make the ansatz $y=e^{\lambda x}$. Evaluating derivatives:
$$y'=\lambda e^{\lambda x}$$
$$y''=\lambda^2 e^{\lambda x}$$
If we substitute this into the differential equation, we obtain:
$$\lambda^2 e^{\lambda x}-2\lambda e^{\lambda x}+e^{\lambda x}=0$$
Factoring gives the following:
$$e^{\lambda x}(\lambda^2-2\lambda+1)=0$$
Hence, we must solve the following quadratic equation for $\lambda$, which is known as the *auxiliary equation*, or *characteristic equation*:
$$\lambda^2-2\lambda+1=0$$
Once you solve for $\lambda$, apply the appropriate general solution for your case. I will leave you to determine which case applies. I will denote the roots by $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

---

These cases are all obtained by applying the principle of superposition.

> **Principle of Superposition:** If $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are two solutions to a linear, second order homogeneous differential equation, then so is: $$y(x)=c_1\cdot y_1(x)+c_2\cdot y_2(x)$$
>   Where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants.

**Case 1:** [Real, Distinct Roots](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RealRoots.aspx): $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in \mathbb{R}$ where $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$:

$$y(x)=c_1 e^{\lambda_1 x}+c_2 e^{\lambda_2 x}$$

**Case 2:** [Complex Roots](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ComplexRoots.aspx): The two roots are given by $\lambda_{1,2}=a\pm bi$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence, by applying [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), we obtain:
$$y(x)=c_1 e^{ax}\cos(bx)+c_2 e^{ax}\sin(bx)$$

**Case 3:** [Real, Repeated Roots](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RepeatedRoots.aspx): $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda$, where $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$
$$y(x)=c_1 e^{\lambda x}+c_2 x e^{\lambda x}$$